how zlib.h in C can have more compression rate than python gzip or zlib library?
I want to convert a C to Python3. I save a file in my C code with zlib.h and gzFile to ".gz".
I know some libraries in Python3 such as zlib, gzip, pandas.DataFrame.pickle(compress = "gzip") can save a file to ".gz" format. However, the compression rate is very different!! How can I perfectly implement the "zlib.h" for C in Python3?
I've tried everything I know how to do.
First, the example C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    void init_genrand64(unsigned long);
    double genrand64_real2(void);

    init_genrand64((unsigned long long)time(NULL));
    double r = 0;

    gzFile fp = gzopen("test_in_C.gz", "wb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 293; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j)
        {
            r = genrand64_real2();
            if(j < 9999)
            {
                gzprintf(fp, "%.8lf,", r);
            }
            else
            {
                gzprintf(fp, "%.8lf\n", r);
            }
        }
    }
    gzclose(fp);
}

Next is all Python3 Codes:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = range(293), data = np.random.rand(10000,293))

#csv, plain txt
df.to_csv("test_dat.csv", index = False, header = False)

#pickle, binary
df.to_pickle("test_dat.pk")

#pickle, compressed binary
df.to_pickle("test_dat.pkgz", compression = "gzip")

#npy, binary
np.save("test_dat.npy", df.values)

import gzip

#npy, compressed binary
with gzip.open("test_dat.npygz", "wb") as f:
    np.save(f, df.values)
    
#csv, compressed binary
with gzip.open("test_dat.gz", "wb") as f:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
            if j < len(df.columns) - 1:
                f.write((str(df.iloc[i,j]) + ",").encode())
            else:
                f.write((str(df.iloc[i,j]) + "\n").encode())

#npy, compressed binary
import zlib
dat = zlib.compress(df.values)
with open("test_dat.zl", "wb") as f:
    f.write(dat)

The size of files:
test_in_C.gz   13MB
test_dat.csv   54MB (56460866B)
test_dat.pk    22MB (23440571B)
test_dat.npy   22MB (23440128B)
test_dat.pkgz  21MB (22104880B)
test_dat.npygz 21MB (22104445B)
test_dat.gz    24MB (25663307B)
test_dat.zl    21MB (22104671B)

In this experiment, we can see the .npygz file has the best compression rate, but the difference with test_in_C.gz originated from C is about double. As you can see, the file from C and file from Python3 are same shape (10000, 293).
How can I reduce this gap? This is very important problem for me, because I will handle very big data(about 800MB per file * 1,000 from C). If size of these files are double, maybe my PC and Python code are bombed.
Thank you for your help.

Have you checked that the uncompressed data written by the C code produces a CSV file that's identical to the one created by Python?

@AndrewHenle  Of course. I checked the file with np.loadtxt(test_in_C.gz) to identicity. Shape, and the decimal place of numbers. In C code, the "%.8lf"s are adjusting the decimal place line.

Using numpy to load the compressed file tells you nothing about the data that was written to disk - no matter how many digits compose each value in the file, you get the same number of values in numpy.  Uncompress the file written by C and see how big it is.  And check the data to see if has the same format.  Is C writing 1234.567 to disk while Python is writing 1234.5678901234 to the file?

@AndrewHenle I checked the files with zcat/gzcat followed your advice, the number of numbers below the point are different. However, I don't think the difference make the double of size.
I found the cause and solution with chatGPT. Cause: the "gzip" library cannot follow the compression rate of original zlib library and the binary file has metadata. Finally the python zlib's default compression level is 1.
Solution: Use zlib directly, convert the data to string, and set the compression level to 9.

import zlib
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10000, 293)

# convert the data to string
data_str = "\n".join(",".join(f"{x:.8f}" for x in row) for row in data)

# Compress the data by using zlib with compression level 9
compressed_data = zlib.compress(data_str.encode(), level=9)

# save the compressed data to gzip file
with open("test_dat_zlib.gz", "wb") as f:
    f.write(compressed_data)

Result:
test_in_C.gz     13MB (13779791B)
test_dat_zlib.gz 13MB (13598171B)

